# Inserting も inside a suru verb

Tags: particles, verbs

I know that しょくじします means "to have a meal". I have trouble understanding the bolded sentence in the following text:

> たたみのへやでしごとをします。**しょくじもします。**

Does it mean that the person also has meals in a tatami room? Is it normal to "insert" the も particle like that between the noun and する?

Comment: "I read books. I also read magazines." ほん**を**よみます。ざっしん**も**よみます。You use the verb よむ twice, and in the second instance を is replaced by も. I don't think it's different for する.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jarmanso7 points out, you can always replace an を (or a が) with a も.

I think part of the confusion might be that the も-less example the OP offers/is familiar with doesn't have an を. しょくじをします and しょくじします are both possible, and are closely related, though there are many who would consider the latter to be a sort of verb in its own right, whereas the former is "doing" a meal. Perhaps like "Partaking of a meal", vs "dining". If this perspective is comfortable for you, then I'd suggest that the も is replacing the を of the former, making it akin to "Partaking also in meals" (or "also takes meals there").

The suggestion that も is "inserted" between noun and verb is a little problematic, because normally you don't have a noun and a verb in the same sentence without some sort of particle after the noun. In casual situations of course, particles are often dropped, but technically this wouldn't be quite grammatical I believe. する-verb nouns are the notable exceptions (so is a noun with the copula です, but you could argue that です isn't 100% a verb in function, even if it is one grammatically), because there the noun+する combination may be considered a complete verb (but is kind of a gray area of sorts).

And of course, in those casual instances I mentioned where a particle might be dropped (さかなたべる？) if you wanted to use a も, you *would* just slip it in "between the noun and the verb" (or to be more accurate: after the noun, regardless of what else might be between the noun and the verb).